# to create ruby project in NetBeans7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans-7.1

I have installed netbeans7-1, ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.2.1, gem1.8.15 . Also install the plugins for ruby. But when I am trying to create a new project having category "Ruby" then projects list have "Ruby Application" and "Ruby Application with existing sources". There is no option for "Ruby on Rails Application".

Can you tell me what may be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess Ruby on Rails is only supported upto Netbeans 7.0. ROR is not supported in higher versions of netbeans like netbeans 7.1. Do give a try on netbeans 7.0 . I am sure it will work

Comment: As I got the issue, I have created the project in command line. Now can u tell me how can I import that folder in netbeans IDE instead of file?

Comment: Ok. Open netbeans and then click on file , then select new project option. There you will get a Choose project which will consist of Categories and projects. From category section choose Ruby and then in project choose ruby on rails with existing source. Click on next. Provide the project folder. Click on finish and start working

Comment: I uninstall the netbeans7.1 and again install 6.8 version and now I have created ruby on rails successfully. But now the problem is to connect to the web server. It is showing "Could not connect to the web server. can not show localhost:3000"; , though I right click on the project and select run. I thing this is a very trivial issue, but I can't. Please help me.

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Comment: GlassFish v3 Domain......by the way, I solve the above issue but another issue is coming that is in the server log file I am getting two errors like "SEVERE: Failed to create JRuby instance." and "SEVERE: library `socket' could not be loaded: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  java/net/URLClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "org/jruby/ext/socket/RubySocket"". So that first time for 2 seconds my web page is opening but after that its redirecting to a page having the content "Something went wrong on the server.
Check the server log for details!"

Comment: Go to your project directory via terminal or command prompt and type rails s.. It will give you link , then click on that link...

Comment: which link do you want to say?

Comment: the one with 3000 port number ,which will be present in the terminal or command prompt after you execute rail s command

Answer (score 1):

sun has dropped support for ROR from netbeans http://www.infoworld.com/d/developer-world/netbeans-ide-drops-ruby-rails-backing-674

you have to install rails manually

go to Tool => Plugins and then click on "Available Plugins", check "ruby on rails" and install it.

Comment: I have install that plugins also. But still problem

Comment: what is issue ? if you have installed rials you should see "Ruby On Rials Application" and "Ruby on Rails Application with existing sourcecode" in new project menu,restart netbeans if it still dons not works

Comment: I uninstall the netbeans7.1 and again install 6.8 version and now I have created ruby on rails successfully. But now the problem is to connect to the web server. It is showing "Could not connect to the web server. can not show http://localhost:3000" , though I right click on the project and select run. I thing this is a very trivial issue, but I can't. Please help me.